# Как сделать выборку в MySQL фильтрацию значений, идущих подряд?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select

Есть таблица `table`. В ней `1` столбец `s1`. Тип значений - целые числа. Стоит задача: вывести те строки, значения которых идут подряд от n кол-во раз.
Пример: есть таблица

[image: Исходная таблица]

Необходимо из нее выбрать значения, идущие подряд 3 и более раз. Т.е. результат должен быть следующим:

[image: Результат]

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Возможный алгоритм решения. 1) Нумеруем записи при сортировке по возрастанию. 2) Используя 2 нумерованные копии, выбираем для каждой записи первой копии такую запись из второй, что разность номеров равна разности значений, причём берём максимум и минимум по второй копии при группировке по первой копии. Причём выбираем только уникальные пары (DISTINCT) значений из второй копии. Это даёт нам диапазоны последовательно идущих значений (от и до). 3) Имея границы значений, выполняем генерацию всех значений диапазонов - на базе опорной таблицы или третьей копии исходной таблицы.

Comment: Альтернативный вариант - хранимая процедура с 2 курсорами. Первый используется для подсчёта количества последовательных значений, второй - для вывода этих значений во временную таблицу, если подсчитанное количество превысило заданный порог. PS. Оба метода требуют. чтобы значения поля были уникальными.

Comment: @Akina Вы перечисляете общие подходы к решению таких задач. Но для конкретно этой задачи все они выглядят излишне громоздкими. Хватит одной процедуры, которая курсором перебирает значения и по условиям складывает во временные таблицы. Уникальность значений не обязательна.

Comment: Чем определяется порядок следования значений в этом столбце?

Comment: @Deft Второй способ - именно то, чём Вы говорите. *Уникальность значений не обязательна.* У автора в примере два значения s1=7. Он их в ответе считает как одно. Так что либо он отбирает уникальные, либо он ориентируется на физический порядок возврата значений (возможно, при некоторой сортировке), скромно умолчав о том, чем этот порядок обеспечен.

Comment: А что такое "подряд" ? В БД нет понятия порядка записей до тех пор, пока не применена сортировка в явном виде. В вашем примере во входных данных две 7, они должны были сбить выдачу 8, если бы сортировка шла по самим номерам

Comment: Сама таблица - это пример. Я специально упростил, чтобы сходу можно было разобраться, что требуется. В действительности там будут сотни тысяч элементов. Сами элементы отсортированы. Решение подсказали на другом сайте: https://toster.ru/q/453749

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.s1 FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.s1, IF (@max = 1, @max := t1.seq, @max := @max) AS "max1", IF (t1.seq = 1, @max := 1, @max := @max) AS "max2" 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT (SELECT @id := @id + 1) AS "id", s1, IF (s1 = @prev + 1, @seq := @seq + 1, @seq := 1) AS "seq",  (SELECT @prev := s1) AS "prev" 
        FROM `table`,  (SELECT @id := 0, @seq := 0, @prev := null) AS init 
    ) AS t1, (SELECT @max := 1) AS init ORDER BY t1.id DESC 
) AS t2 WHERE t2.max1 >= 3 ORDER BY t2.id
```

Сам ответ подсказали на https://toster.ru/q/453749